# How can I maintain a running total in a SQL Server database using VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am using Visaul Studio 2010 to build a Windows Forms application to maintain a table in an SQL Server 2008 database. The table is named `CASHBOOK` and here are the further details:

```
DATE    | DESCRIPTION    | DEBIT   | CREDIT    | BALANCE
--------|----------------|---------|-----------|---------
1/1/2011| CASH BALANCE   |         |           | 5000
1/1/2011| SALES          |  2500   |           | 7500
2/1/2011| PURCHASE       |         |  3000     | 4500
2/1/2011| RENT           |         |  4000     |  500
2/1/2011| SALES          |  5000   |           | 5500
```

I can use `CASHBOOKTABLEADAPTER.INSERT(...)` to insert appropriately, but my problem is how do I update the `BALANCE` column?

Comment: http://www.livephysics.com/ptools/convert-case.php to convert to a sensible case en masse.

Comment: One issue you need to think about is if you'll be inserting rows historically (i.e. not just in ascending date order) - say you insert another row  on 1/1/2011, you'd then end up having to update Balance for ALL the subsequent rows which could be a nasty hit

Comment: I would say that ...you should not ! These things should be done at the lowest level: in SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an insert with a subquery, something like following:

```
INSERT INTO CASHBOOK  ( DESCRIPTION, DEBIT, BALANCE )
'asdf', 2500, SELECT TOP(1) BALANCE FROM CASHBOOK + 2500
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit heavy handed, but here's a way to update the full table with balance information.

```
update
   a
set
   a.Balance = (
      select sum(isnull(x.debit, 0.0) - isnull(x.credit, 0.0))
      from cashbook x
      where x.Date < a.Date
      or (x.Date = a.Date and x.ID <= a.ID)
   ) + (
      select top 1 y.Balance
      from cashbook y
      where y.debit is null
      and y.credit is null
      order by y.ID
   )
from
   cashbook a
```

Now that's useful only if you HAVE to have the balance in the table.  A more appropriate solution might be to create a UDF that encompasses this logic and call that to calculate the balance field for a specific row only when you need it.  It really all depends on your usage.

```
create function dbo.GetBalance(@id int) returns decimal(12, 2) as
begin

declare @result decimal(12, 2) = 0.0

select
       @result = (
          select sum(isnull(x.debit, 0.0) - isnull(x.credit, 0.0))
          from cashbook x
          where x.Date < a.Date
          or (x.Date = a.Date and x.ID <= a.ID)
       ) + (
          select top 1 y.Balance
          from cashbook y
          where y.debit is null
          and y.credit is null
          order by y.ID
       )
from
   cashback a
where
   a.ID = @id

return @result

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to?  This is something that should be calculated as a reporting / viewing function.  I would suggest either creating a view with a running total column (various ways to achieve this).

Alternatively if you're viewing this in VB.Net calculate it in your app.

Comment: Creating a View with a running total column: How do you suggest this column is populated - via a triangular join? Work required grows proportional to the square of the number of rows. Calculate it in the App: So the OP would need to bring back every row to their application then sum them all each time?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Joel, you should be calculating this at runtime, not storing the running totals in the database.  Here's an example of how to figure out the running totals using a recursive cte in sql server:

```
declare @values table (ID int identity(1,1), Value decimal(4,2))
declare @i int

insert into @values values (1.00)
insert into @values values (2.00)
insert into @values values (3.00)
insert into @values values (4.00)
insert into @values values (5.00)
insert into @values values (6.00)

select @i=min(ID) from @values

;with a as
(
    select ID, Value, Value as RunningTotal
    from @values
    where ID=@i

    union all
    select b.ID, b.Value, cast(b.Value + a.RunningTotal as decimal(4,2)) as RunningTotal
    from @values b
        inner join a
            on b.ID=a.ID+1

)
select * from a
```

here's a blog on recursive queries: [Recursive CTEs](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/cte-and-hierarchical-queries)

Also [here's](http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=7601) a lengthy discusson about running totals.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem with recursive CTEs is the maximum depth limit of 32767, which can be prohibitive in a production environment.

In this solution you add an id column that is ordinal to the transaction sequence and then update the balance column in place.

```
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1) not null
, [DATE] date not null
, [DESCRIPTION] varchar(80) null
, [DEBIT] money not null default(0)
, [CREDIT] money not null default(0)
, [BALANCE] money not null default(0)
);

declare @bal money=0;

insert into @t([DATE],[DESCRIPTION],[DEBIT],[CREDIT],[BALANCE])
select '1/1/2011','CASH BALANCE',0,0,5000 UNION ALL
select '1/1/2011','SALES',2500,0,0 UNION ALL
select '2/1/2011','PURCHASE',0,3000,0 UNION ALL
select '2/1/2011','RENT',0,4000,0 UNION ALL
select '2/1/2011','SALES',5000,0,0;


set @bal=(select top 1 [BALANCE] from @t order by id); /* opening balance is stored but not computed, so we simply look it up here. */

update t
set @bal=t.[BALANCE]=(t.[DEBIT]-t.[CREDIT])+@bal
output
inserted.*
from @t t
left join @t t0 on t0.id+1=t.id; /*should order by id by default, but to be safe we force the issue here. */
```